# Question on groups and homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\Phi$ be a group-valued function with domain $P$. That is for each $p \in P$, is a group. This is called a family of groups parametrized by $P$. We will denote $\Phi(p)$ by $G_p$, $∗p$.
Now denote $\{f : P \to \bigcup_{p\in P}G_p \mid f(p) \in G_p\}$ by $Q$.

What exactly is happening here? I understand the first part. The first part, $\Phi(p)$, you have a function, or map, that for each element of the domain it gives you a group. The second part is what's confusing me. What is the function $f$ doing?

Answer (score 0):

The condition on the function $f$ is that $f(p)$ is an element of $G_p$.

Say, $P=\{1,2\}$. Then you have two group $G_1,G_2$ and you consider a function $f$ from $\{1,2\}$ to $G_1\cup G_2$ such that $f(1) \in G_1$ and $f(2) \in G_2$.

Note that $Q$ is the set of *all* such functions $f$.

Intuitively you could say $f$ is a function that choses one element from each of the groups $G_p$.

Comment: My professor put this as a addedum to show an example: "Let P = R, and Φ(r) = R,+. Observe that Q
r∈R R, ∗ is simply the set of real valued
functions of a real variable with the usual addition of functions. " Is that the same concept?

Comment: Yes, when you define in addition an operation between two elements $f,g$ of $Q$ by $(f\ast g )(p) = f(p) \ast_p g(p)$. Note that $f \ast g$ is again in $Q$ as $ f(p) \ast_p g(p) \in G_p$ for each $p \in P$

Comment: oooooh. I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$Q$ is the collection of all functions from $P$ to the union $$\bigcup_{p\in P} G_p $$ such that $f(p) \in G_p$ for all $p\in P$. I guess the idea is that $P$ is some index set, and all  the $G_p$ are subgroups of a larger group, say $G$.

For instance, if $P = \mathbb{N}$, and $G_n = n\mathbb{Z} < \mathbb{Z}$ for all $n\in P$, then $Q$ consists of all sequences $\{x_n\} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n\mid x_n$ for all $n$.